# Identar, indentar, ou endentar?

Tags: ortografia

Referente à prática de programação de ter um código com uma boa [Indentação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o), me veio a pergunta, qual termo estaria correto para se referir à utilização do recuo de um texto em relação à sua margem:

1. Identar
2. Indentar
3. Endentar

Segundo artigo sobre [Identação ou Indentação](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/identacao-ou-indentacao/), ao meu ver parece certo utilizar **Indentar**, gostaria de informações mais técnicas sobre a utilização, e se realmente esse é o termo correto.

Outra coisa, existe diferença entre [brasil](/questions/tagged/brasil) e [portugal](/questions/tagged/portugal) para o termo?

Comment: [in·den·tar](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/indentar)

Comment: @JorgeB., editei a pergunta se existe diferença para a utlização do termo em Portugal e Brasil.

Comment: David, o artigo diz que é *indentar* que está correto. É isso que queres dizer? Tens *identar* na pergunta.

Comment: Por curiosidade, pesquisei o término do castelhano (*sangrar*) para português, e diz o dicionário que é o mesmo, *sangrar*, mas os dicionários monolíngues não reconhecem este significado. Um erro grave, acho (por parte do dicionário bilíngue)

Comment: bah! Como programador, todo mundo que conheço usa identar, bom saber!

Comment: Embora o estrangeirismo venha de Indent, sua pronúncia em português como indentar é muito difícil, pra não dizer impossível pra alguns, identar foi sua versão fonética natural. E afirmo que há 30 anos vivendo no mundo da programação, nunca vi ninguém pronunciar indentar, uma coisa é o que alguém resolveu registrar no dicionário outra coisa é o que de fato falamos e pronunciamos com clareza. Sinceramente todos nós programadores falamos e escrevemos identação. Um código bem identado é humanamente muito mais legível.

Comment: Luciano, exatamente por esse motivo fiz a pergunta, e me pego falando `identar` kkk

Comment: Nossa, sempre usei 'identar' e nunca sequer imaginei que pudesse haver controvérsia a respeito dessa palavra...bom saber.

Comment: Sempre vi e ouvi "indentar" — e não vejo como poderia ser "quase impossível de pronunciar" para uma pessoa que consegue falar "indo", "indelével", etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sempre que for adicionar recuos (sejam com espaços ou tabulações) no código fonte é recomendado o termo **indentar**. Apesar do termo ser um neologismo, por derivar do inglês *[indent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/indent)* e ser usado na computação, este seria um termo bem adequado.

A palavra **identar** não parece estar correta, tanto que o autocorretor muda para indentar e não encontramos o verbete no dicionário.

Já a endentação tem relação com a junção dos *dentes* de uma engrenagem, a indentação se relaciona com a criação de certos zigue-zagues no código, por conta do recuo.

O termo de sangrar visto nos comentários tem relação à [comunicação impressa](http://www.primastampa.com.br/artigo/o-que-e-sangria-e-marcas-de-corte), mas com mesmo significado. Geralmente sangrar o documento para que as páginas tenham uma margem de segurança na impressão ou no corte.

**EDIT:**

Como visto em alguns comentários, pode ocorrer durante a pronúncia da palavra acabar ignorando o 'n', mas a palavra continuará usando a derivação do inglês com 'n' na sua forma escrita. O português escrito é diferente do falado e não é comum escrever do jeito que falamos. Um exemplo é ouvir, pelo menos aqui no Brasil, frases com a queda dos 's' nos plurais: *Os menino*, mas nem por isso escreveremos assim.

Answer (score 6):

[***Indentar***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/indentar) é a forma correta, de acordo com o artigo que você localizou.

Answer (score -1):

Entendo que *indentar* possa ser empregado no âmbito da informática, por influência da língua inglesa, mas, particularmente, considero o neologismo desnecessário, e *ipso facto* condenável, uma vez que já possuímos em bom português o termo *endentar,* utilizado precisamente com o mesmo sentido no jargão tipográfico.

Comment: Mauro, bem-vindo à comunidade. Para uma boa resposta deverias apoiar em fonte fiável a afirmação do uso de *endentar* no jargão tipográfico. Não encontrei em dicionário nenhum.